# Change specific keys of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an two dimensional array called `$array`. After another question here, I know how to change the whole child array from a two dimensional array like this:

Code

```
$keys = array(0, 1);    
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
      foreach ($array[$key] as $key2 => $value) {  
          $array[$key][$key2] = str_replace($stamm, $stamm2, $value);
        }
    }
```

How is it possible to change only `$array[0][3],$array[0][4]` and `$array[1]`?

$array use `$stamm` + ending of an verb for a time for example "ons".
I have to change for some cases the root of the verb (`$stamm`).
With the code above it works perfectly to change the whole `array[0]` and `array[1]`.                                                                          .

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on what you really intend to do ? I mean the functional part, what you are trying to achieve?
Then we could probably provide a better solution / explanation
Thank you

Comment: Definitly ! Thank you :) I believe some simple solutions have already been provided below. As an complement, you could also "type" your values, y that I mean making money pattern with stamms and endings. then if you work with simple objects, you can check against types which would be probably be more readable, ie : if($value instanceof Stamm) then... A little more complicated, but probably easier to read later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you simply do this

```
$array[0][3] = //your value;
$array[0][4] =  //your value;
```

and if you want to change all value of `$array[1]`:

```
foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {  
      $array[1][$key] = //your value;
    }
```

**EDIT** to do all this with a foreach :

```
foreach ($keys as $key) { 
  foreach ($array[$key] as $key2 => $value) { 
      if(($key==0 && ($key2 == 3 || $key2 == 4)) || ($key == 1) ) 
          $array[$key][$key2] = //your value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before the foreach-loop their is a if-loop. I have many, similar if-loops and I will change often some parts auf the array (conjugation script). I thought it would be shorter and more elegant to do this with foreach-loops.

Comment: Why not `foreach ($array[1] as &$value) { $value = $new_value; }`?

Comment: @Grischa check the `EDIT` part of my answer for automated solution

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Thanks this is what I was searching for. Would it be more elegant to change `&& ($key2 == 3 || $key2 == 4)` to an array like  $key2 = array(3, 4) ?

Comment: yes you can actually add your accepted values in an array like this `$acceptedValues = array(1,2);` then `if(in_array($key2, $acceptedValues ))`